# Django REST Framework: SlugRelatedField for indirectly-related attribute?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Profile model that has a one-to-one relationship with Django's User model, and I have another model, called Permission (unrelated to Django's internal idea of permissions), that has a foreign key to Profile.  Like this: (I've removed most of the fields here, for simplicity)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser

class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    django_user = models.OneToOneField(DjangoUser)
    default_account = models.ForeignKey(Account)

class Permission(models.Model):
    # Which user has the permission
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, db_index=True)
    # Which account they have the permission on
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, db_index=True)
```

I want to make a serializer for Permission, that will create objects like this:

```
{
  "user": "me@example.com",
  "account": 123
}
```

where the value of "account" is the account's primary key (so that's easy, I can use a PrimaryKeyRelatedField) and the value of "user" is the user's email address (this is the part I haven't figured out yet, because the email address is not stored directly on the Profile object, it's on the associated DjangoUser object).  Note also that this is NOT read-only -  when creating a Permission it does need to be able to deserialize from an email address to a Profile object.

Some things I have tried so far, for representing the user on the Permission serializer ...

1.

```
user = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=False)
```

With this one, if I POST an email address (or primary key or anything else) as the "user", it returns a 400 error saying `{"user": "This field is required."}`, as if I didn't include the field at all.

2.

```
user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='django_user.email')
```

With this one, I get `AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'django_user.email'`.  Same thing happens if I use `'django_user__email'`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According to Django REST Framework serializer reference (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments):

> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. May be a method that only takes a self argument, such as URLField(source='get_absolute_url'), or may use dotted notation to traverse attributes, such as EmailField(source='user.email').

So, if `source='user.email'` is not working, you can try to create a method (e.g. `get_user_email`), use it in `source` field and make it return the user email manually.

Comment: As specified in the original question, the field is NOT read-only.  It needs to be able to deserialize, not just serialize.

Comment: Using `source` doesn't mean it's read-only. What happens when you try to deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try: `user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='django_user__email')`? Sometimes in Django double underscore notation for queries can be useful.
Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Comment: The question specifically says that that causes an AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

I took the time to write some code for better understanding of your question. If you want to fully support CRUD operations on your `PermissionsSerializer` you need to nest `Profile` object so you can read its attributes.
These are the serializers I suggest you implement.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Permission, Profile, Account


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    django_user = UserSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('django_user',)


class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = ProfileSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields = ('user', 'account')
```

And the output is:

```
{
        "user": {
            "django_user": {
                "username": "admin",
                "email": "admin@mail.com"
            }
        },
        "account": 1
    }
```

Hope this can help you, if this is the approach is useful and you want to make it write-able look at ( http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships ).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):

> `source`
>
> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. May
>   be a method that only takes a `self` argument, such as
>   `URLField(source='get_absolute_url')`, or may use dotted notation to
>   traverse attributes, such as `EmailField(source='user.email')`.

**However, there has never been a successful attempt with the dotted notation in my projects. I always ended up using an instance method or a property instead.**

Recently I dived into the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1169) of `ModelSerializer`, and found something interesting:

```
def build_field(self, field_name, info, model_class, nested_depth):
    """
    Return a two tuple of (cls, kwargs) to build a serializer field with.
    """
    if field_name in info.fields_and_pk:
        model_field = info.fields_and_pk[field_name]
        return self.build_standard_field(field_name, model_field)

    elif field_name in info.relations:
        relation_info = info.relations[field_name]
        if not nested_depth:
            return self.build_relational_field(field_name, relation_info)
        else:
            return self.build_nested_field(field_name, relation_info, nested_depth)

    elif hasattr(model_class, field_name):
        return self.build_property_field(field_name, model_class)

    elif field_name == self.url_field_name:
        return self.build_url_field(field_name, model_class)

    return self.build_unknown_field(field_name, model_class)
```

The part that might handle dotted notation traversal should be `elif field_name in info.relations`.

- According to the traceback of my project, `field_name` may be something like `"django_user.email"`, and `info` was a NamedTuple with the `relations` attribute of an OrderedDict.
- And the keys of the `info.relations` OrderedDict was the field names of `ForeignKey`s and `ManyToManyField`s.
- So really, dotted notation traversal wouldn't be handled by this.

At last, dotted notation traversal was handled by `return self.build_unknown_field(...)` which [raised an exception](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1296).